# Enterprise custom field input by look up to external data MS Project Server

Tags: c#, sharepoint, lookup, custom-fields, project-server

Hi i want to set a project custom field input like autocomplete look up from external data / external lists.

I am using MS Project Server 2013 system which in Sharepoint platform.

Actually, I have plan by modifying MS Project Server solution starter which made for custom field can look up from user group data. I have tried but it is difficult to change many things.

Is there any easiest way? Or maybe there is custom solution that has been made?
Please explain in simple way in c# programming or maybe javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are any new features for that in 2013, but we synchronize external sources into Lookup tables assigned to  Enterprise Custom Fields. We do that using PSI service [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclookuptable_di_pj14mref%28v=office.15%29.aspx). And we do that using C# because only .NET supports DataSets which are the main data container to communicate with a Project Server through PSI